# Getting a substring in C

Tags: c, strstr

I have a string in the following format:
"R:  625.5m E:-32768m"

What's the most efficient way to pull out the 625.5?

Comment: Use a regular expression. Now you have two problems. :)

Comment: I take it back... what's the quickest and dirtiest way to get this done?

Comment: Sorry, my poor joke. I actually answered the question, too. Use `sscanf`.

Comment: As always with these "how do I parse this" questions, it would help to know which part vary and how much?  For instance will it always start with just 3 characters before the number, or could it be more, and is the length of the number variable, can it be in European form (with a comma decimal), will it always end with 'm', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) to read formatted information from the string.

```
sscanf(mystr, "R: %f", &myFloat);
```

Comment: And - just like with regular expressions - now you have two problems.

Comment: @Zack: parsing was already the problem. Regular expressions are the problem on top of that parsing problem.

Comment: What I meant was, `*scanf` are *also* a problem on top of the original parsing problem.  See my responses to other answers.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks guys.  1. Trim off the R:  2. Trim off an arbitrary amount of whitespace.  3. Use sscanf

Comment: @Zack: Assuming i18n isn't an issue (although it's a valid edge case), sscanf isn't nearly as bad as you're making it out to be.

Comment: i18n always ends up being an issue eventually, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf` is a good candiate to parse simple strings with fixed format.

Comment: OP searching most efficient way

Comment: @Svisstack: see the comments. He wants "quick and dirty", not "three milliseconds faster than `sscanf`". `sscanf` *is* the correct answer.

Comment: @Svisstack: but hasn't said whether he cares more about run-time efficiency or programmer efficiency, nor whether he needs the result as a string or a number, nor how much the string may vary, whether he's okay with modifying the original string, etc. Without knowing all of that, `sscanf` is about as good a choice as any and better than most (certainly much more reasonable than anything that involves modifying the input).

Comment: `*scanf` have enough surprises hidden in their definition that they should, IMO, never be used.